# Provide @property for const and non-const structures in D

Tags: properties, constants, d

I define a simple struct this way:

```
struct Person{
    private string _name;

    @property ref string name() { return _name; }
}
```

The `@property` annotation is really cool, but I don't know how should I use it properly.

The above is quite ok, but I cannot pass a `Person` to a function requiring `in Person` for instance:

```
void fun(in Person p) { ... }
```

To avoid copying `Person` I have to declare the parameter with `ref`, though I don't modify it.

So how to combine the property syntax with const-correctness?

---

edit:
To follow up, can the same apply to looping?

```
void fun(in Person[] people) {
    foreach(Person p; people) { ... }
}
```

now I don't want to copy person, but I can't use `ref Person` since it's const. So I have to write `ref const(Person) p` in the loop which becomes loong.

Comment: "To avoid copying Person I have to declare the parameter with ref". Why? Just remove ref from property. BTW. it should be return _name not return name

Comment: @Kozzi11 but if I remove `ref` then I won't be able to assign to `name`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Normally, what you'd do would be

```
@property string name() const { return _name; }
@property void name(string value) { _name = value; }
```

and you wouldn't bother with `ref` (certainly, for a `string`, there isn't much point). For more complex types that you want to avoid copying, you can return by `const ref`, e.g.

```
@property ref const(Foo) foo() const { return _foo; }
@property void foo(Foo value) { _foo = value; }
```

You *could* overload the setter so that it accepted `ref Foo` in addition to `Foo`, but there isn't much point, since you'd be copying the passed in `Foo` to assign it to `_foo` anyway.

And if you *really* want to, you can return by `ref` from the getter and overload it, e.g.

```
@property ref const(Foo) foo() const { return _foo; }
@property ref Foo foo() { _foo; }
```

in which case the non-const overload can be used as a setter, but if you're going to do that, why bother with a property? At that point, you might as well just make the member variable public, because the property isn't protecting it at all. By returning non-const `ref`, you've lost control over how the member variable is set and have effectively exposed it as a public member variable except that you have the extra plumbing of the function around it. The only advantages that it gives you are that you can do something before returning and that the type's invariant (if any) will be called when the property is called (whereas it won't with a public member variable), but because the variable can be set without you're control at that point, those benefits are of questionable value in comparison to the simplicity of simply making the member variable public.

So, in general, the first example is the way to go, and once in a while, the second is better, but it's arguably pointless to go with the third example.

**EDIT:**

As [Kozzi11 points out](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24161593/160887), you can implement the 3rd example as

```
@property auto ref foo() inout { return _foo; }
```

or

```
@property ref inout(Foo) foo() inout { return _foo; }
```

instead of having two functions, but my point about it not really being much better than a public member variable still applies.

**EDIT 2:** With regards to your edit to the question...

If you want to avoid copying in the loop, you're going to have to be explicit with the type.

```
foreach(p; people) { ... }
```

will work, but it will copy each individual `Person` as it iterates over `people`, whereas

```
foreach(ref Person p; people) { ...}
```

or

```
foreach(ref const(Person) p; people) { ...}
```

will avoid copying each `Person`.

Comment: Well where the "@property auto ref foo() inout { return _foo; }" differs from a public member is that you can return different values ex. "@property auto ref foo() inout {  if (bar) return _foo; else _foo2; }"

Comment: Jonathan, thank you. Your answer is thorough. Regarding the loop, I will choose the 3rd option, but I must admit that I'd expect something more compact from D!

Comment: @Parobay Improvements have been suggested - e.g. https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=4707 - but they have yet to be approved or implemented.

Answer (score 3):

What about this:

```
import std.stdio;

void someFun(in Person person) {
    writeln(person.name);
}

struct Person {
    private string _name;
    @property auto ref name() inout { return _name; }
}

void main(string[] args)
{
    auto person = Person("Osoba Nova");
    someFun(person);
    stdin.readln;
}
```

EDIT: for loop you can ommit type

```
void fun(in Person[] people) {
    foreach (p; people) {
        writeln(p.name);
    }
}
```

Comment: wow, this is nice, one function and not 2 as in @burner case. But how does `inout` work, I can't map this to my C++ knowledge.. ?

Comment: **`inout`** will generate all posible version of that method with correct qualifiers (const, immutable ...). [doc](http://dlang.org/function.html#inout-functions)

Comment: @Parobay C++ has nothing like `inout`. An `inout` parameter (in this case, the `this` pointer) is treated as `const`, but it retains its type. The primary advantage is with parameters that get returned from a function. By accepting `inout`, a function can accept mutable, `const`, and `immutable` arguments and return the same type, whereas if `const` had been used, you'd always end up with `const` being returned. In this case, by using `inout` on the member, it should return `_name` with the same constness as the this pointer rather than always const as would occur if it were marked with const

Comment: @Kozzi11 Technically, no functions are generated. You only have the one that's declared. It's just that the caller treats the return type as the same constness as the variable that the function is being called on. You only get additional functions being generated when templates are involved, which is not the case here.

Comment: If I ommit the type (just type `foreach(p; people)`) then what's the type of `p`? The same as of `people`?

Comment: use **`writeln(typeid(typeof(p)));`** to find out type

Comment: Ok this is great. One last thing with long type is a lambda that I use on the passed `in Person[]`: `auto f = (ref const(Person) p ) => p.name;`  Can I skip the type somehow?

Comment: I dont know. The only way which come to my mind is using type alias: `alias RCP = const(Person); auto f = (ref RCP p ) => p.name;`

Answer (score 1):

a property function is just a function, so you can overload it.

```
@property ref const(string) name() const { return name_; }
@property ref string name() { return name_; }
```

Comment: You'll need it to return `ref const(string)` on the first overload, and you need to change the name of the member variable, or you'll get infinite recursion and blow the stack.