# Const member function vs const return type

Tags: constants, d

In D I can specify const functions, like in c++:

```
struct Person {
    string name;

    // these two are the same?
    const string getConstName() { return name; }     
    string getConstName2() const { return name; }   
}
```

It seems that the above two are the same meaning. Is it true?

If so how can I return a `const` string rather than define a const function?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Provide @property for const and non-const structures in D](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24160745/provide-property-for-const-and-non-const-structures-in-d)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The two are identical. Function attributes can go on either side of a function. e.g.

```
pure Bar foo() {...}
```

and

```
Bar foo() pure {...}
```

are identical. The same goes for `pure`, `nothrow`, `const`, etc. This is probably fine for most attributes, but it becomes quite annoying when `const`, `immutable`, or `inout` is involved, because they can all affect the return type. In order for those attributes to affect the return type, parens must be used. e.g.

```
const(Bar) foo() {...}
```

returns a `const Bar`, whereas

```
Bar foo const {...}
```

and

```
const Bar foo() {...}
```

return a mutable `Bar`, but the member function itself is `const`. In most cases what you want is probably either

```
Bar foo() {...}
```

or

```
const(Bar) foo() const {...}
```

since it's frequently the case that having a `const` member function forces you to return `const` (particularly if you're returning a member variable), but you can have any combination of `const` between the member function and its return type just so long as it works with what the function is doing (e.g. returning a mutable reference to a member variable doesn't work from a `const` function).

Now personally, I wish that putting `const` on the left-hand side were illegal, particularly when the excuse that all function attributes can go on either side of the function isn't really true anyway (e.g. [`static`, `public`, and `private` don't seem to be able to go on the right-hand side](https://issues.dlang.org/show_bug.cgi?id=12930)), but unfortunately, that's the way it is at this point, and I doubt that it's going to change, because no one has been able to convince Walter Bright that it's a bad idea to let `const` go on the left.

However, it *is* generally considered bad practice to put `const`, `immutable`, or `inout` on the left-hand side of the function unless they're using parens and thus affect the return type, precisely because if they're on the left without parens, you immediately have to question whether the programmer who did it meant to modify the function or the return type. So, allowing it on the left is pretty pointless (aside perhaps for generic code, but it's still not worth allowing it IMHO).

Comment: One more thing. What about `const` for functions (not member methods). Functions cannot be `const` in the meaning of methods, so does `const` always refer to the return type in functions?

Comment: @user3733425 I never thought about that before, but trying it out, it looks like if you put `const` on the right-hand side of a free function, you get an error, but if you put it on the left, it's just ignored. So, yes, it always refers to the function and not the type, but for some reason, the compiler ignores it when it's on the left rather than giving an error.

Comment: IMHO that should be considered a bug. The behaviour should be the same. Maybe other compilers do different (which I doubt as they share the same frontend)?

Comment: @DejanLekic I tend to agree, but there are a number of cases where the compiler ignores attributes by design (the argument for it usually has to do with either generic code or when a large section of a file is marked with the attribute at once via a label or block). IIRC, there's at least one open bug on the topic, but I don't know if it will be changed or not.